# Не могу запустить php7.2-fpm

Tags: php, linux, php-fpm

Не получается запустить php7.2-fpm. Ругается так:

```
Failed to restart php7.2-fpm.service: Unit php7.2-fpm.service is masked
```

Comment: Попробуйте заинсталить php заново
1. sudo apt install php7.2-fpm
2. sudo service php7.2-fpm restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
sudo systemctl unmask php7.2-fpm.service
sudo systemctl enable php7.2-fpm.service
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service
```